# Sharing a DS40 Printer with CUPS

Tags: printing, share, cups

I am trying to set up a DS40 as a shared printer on a Raspberry Pi using CUPS. I have Raspbian and CUPS installed.

I tried setting up the printer with the CUPS drivers included for this make/model, but printing was VERY slow, so I decided to try to set it up as a Raw printer in CUPS with the client machine taking care of the printer drivers.

So I set up the printer in CUPS as Make: **Raw** and Model: **Raw Queue (en)**. In Windows on the client PC, I've added a network printer with the correct URL and installed it with the correct driver. I know this is the correct driver because I've tested it with the same printer connected via USB.

When I send the printer a job, the job shows up in the queue in the CUPS web interface, with the status "sending data to printer." The status stays in that state for several minutes and then switches to "Unable to send data to printer."

When it switches to the "Unable to send data to printer" state, here is the error log output (from /var/log/cups)

```
E [17/Feb/2015:20:18:59 +0000] [Job 18] Unable to send data to printer.
E [17/Feb/2015:20:18:59 +0000] Failed to update TXT record for Dai Nippon Printing DS40 @ raspberrypi: -2
E [17/Feb/2015:20:18:59 +0000] [cups-deviced] PID 3308 (snmp) stopped with status 1!
E [17/Feb/2015:20:19:08 +0000] [CGI] Unable to get PPD file /printers/Dai_Nippon_Printing_DS40.ppd: 404 - Not Found
E [17/Feb/2015:20:19:35 +0000] [CGI] Unable to get PPD file /printers/Dai_Nippon_Printing_DS40.ppd: 404 - Not Found
E [17/Feb/2015:20:20:11 +0000] Failed to update TXT record for Dai Nippon Printing DS40 @ raspberrypi: -2
E [17/Feb/2015:20:24:00 +0000] [Job 18] Stopping unresponsive job!
```

I've googled everything and can't seem to find anything that helps. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Also, I'm not married to CUPS, I just want a way to quickly print to a shared printer connected to a Raspberry Pi. I've seen some people mention lprng, but can't find a good tutorial for how to set it up on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: How large was the file you've printed (or were trying to print...) using the CUPS driver included?

Comment: Does the file at `/printers/Dai_Nippon_Printing_DS40.ppd` exist (or use `where`)? If yes then try and rename it (and delete if that solves it). It might be a lock file. CUPS is very problematic on the Pi.. heck, on Linux.

Comment: I did `locate *.ppd` and didn't come up with any Dai Nippon ppds :/

Answer (score 1):

See this [good tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=108737&p=747774&hilit=lprng#p747774) for how to set up lprng on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Following the "bring the content here" principle it would be advisable to at least summarize what's written over there (I see that repeating a good written tutorial does not want to be repeated however).